Apache2 Redirect www to https ... this is killing me trying to figure this out
Server Ubuntu 22.04
apache2 -v 2.4.52
Website alias for this question:  example.com
I have configured and enabled my virtual host sites-enabled example.conf file as shown below.  Default is disabled.  My site has no .htaccess file.  When I go example.com in the browser, site launches and SSL checks okay (padlock).  When I go http://example.com, site launches and SSL checks okay (padlock).  However, when I go www.example.com, site launches but SSL fails (shows site insecure, padlock red).  I thought I set up the redirect properly in example.conf but I guess I am missing something.  Please review my .conf file below and suggest changes to or trouble shooting method to help me get this problem sorted out.
<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example  
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>


issue:

incorrect ssl configuration
duplicated virtual host

solution:

a single certificate should cover both your domain, you can obtain it by following command

sudo certbot --apache -d example.com -d www.example.com



simplify your apache configuraion

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem
    
    # Ensure that www.example.com redirects to example.com
    <If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'www.example.com'">
        Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
    </If>
</VirtualHost>



I will give the above a try.  Quick question - why is SSLCertificateFile fullchain.pen vs cert.pem?

nabin - I updated my config file per your suggestion above.  It works with Chromium and Edge but not Firefox or Safari.  In other words www shows secure with Chromium and Edge but does not show secure with Firefox or Safari.  I like your simplification though and will keep using it.  I need fo figure out why different browsers are reacting differently.

nabin  - Further testing on the above mentioned config file shows no change in SSL connection if I remove all of the explicit certificate paths. Apache seems to handle it fine without needing them. Further testing shows different behavior across browsers. Edge and Chromium will resolve www as secure. Firefox and Safari will not resolve www as secure.
